# How to determine the "top" activity in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

We are developing a fair complex Android application consisting of several different Activities.  Is there a way to determine which of those is the current one?

It seems like a simple thing, but I'm not even sure what keywords to search for.

Comment: I would like to know, from where you are going to search for the top most activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my method:

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
//Get the info from the currently running task.
List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > taskInfo = activityManager.getRunningTasks(1); 
Log.d(TAG, "TOP Activity ::" + taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName());
```

Perrmission needed in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
```

More info:  [**How to get the current top most activity?**](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/CEYJK4XoZT4)

Comment: I found an example of the ActivityManager code, but there was no mention at all of the necessary permission.  Thanks!!

Comment: beware that most users won't like your app if it needs `GET_TASKS` permission. This is considered highly dangerous and suspicious and makes your app look like spyware. JesusS answer is better because you don't need any special permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Study the `Application`class and create your own custom class extending Application. In the application class, add a field `Activity currentActivity;`

In the onCreate() of every Activity you make you should do

```
CustomApp app = (CustomApp)getApplication();
app.currentActivity = this;
```

Or better create a BaseActivity extending Activity and make your activities extend BaseActivity so you dont need to write that in every onCreate

That you can check what activity is the top one wherever you want.

Regards